# Is there some way to bump my question?

Tags: support, questions

I asked a question few days ago, and while it received few upvotes, no one answered it. I'd like to "bump" it, so that it goes to the top. Can I do it? How can I do it?

Comment: Not really, you can try offering a bounty but there isn't any method that I'm aware of to "bump" a question to the top.

Comment: You *can* edit your question, which is what I tend to do; even a null edit puts it as "active"

Comment: @tac But please make only meaningful edits. Null edits are abusive.

Answer (score 6):

Technically any activity on the question will get it back on the front page, but bounties are the real way to get your question more visibility. See [this main meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/145982) for more information

Answer (score 1):

Any question with neither upvoted nor accepted answers will be automatically bumped to the top from time to time, but typically that only happens a few times a year.  If you want to draw attention to your question, the best way is to offer a bounty.